# PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber not working correctly

Tags: android, phonenumberutils

I passed '55' to `isGlobalPhoneNumber`, and it returns 'true'.

I want it only return true for US phone numbers xxx-xxx-xxxxx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`55` is a valid phone number according to the [definition Android provides in its source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.java#L82) (as context-free grammar):

```
global-phone-number = ["+"] 1*( DIGIT / written-sep )
written-sep         = ("-"/".")
```

Whether or nor this definition is suitable for your application is, of course, independent of that definition.